# AJAX success getting a certain value of object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function

So I'm polling my server for information. Below is what I get back through firebug, but I'm only wanting the new notifications to post into their div if the response.notification_status value of 1 is met. Because as soon as it polls it again that very notification is set to the value of 2.

```
 {"num":1,"notification_id":"783","notification_content":
    "Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall","notification_throughurl"
        :"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=663","notification_triggeredby":"85",
    "notification_status":"1"
        ,"notification_time":"2015-11-08 01:58:22"}
```

And my actual success and what I've tried.

```
success: function(response){
if(response.notification_status = 1){
//PREPEND NOTIFICATION
}
```

Comment: You're assigning 1 to `response.notification_status`

Comment: Okay,, So how would I get the actual value of 1 and not 2 through the response?

Comment: @TheRiverSceneMusic, As you are trying to compare, use `==` or `===`. Right now you are assigning value

Comment: Is there any difference between the two @RayonDabre

Comment: == vs === http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons

Comment: `===` are strict equality operator which also checks the type of values.

Comment: Would I have to wrap the number in single quotes too?

Comment: @TheRiverSceneMusic Only if you use `===`. If you don't type check it does not matter if you're comparing with an int or string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem right now is that the operator `=`, that you are using in your `if` statement is the assignment operator, and cannot be used to compare values. What you need is the `==` operator. So you would need to do something like this:

```
success: function(response){
if(response.notification_status == 1){
//PREPEND NOTIFICATION
}
```